# Exception access violation - Even after UAC disabled

Tags: java

A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:

EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x00000001801238e7, pid=2232, tid=5880

JRE version: 6.0_45-b06
 Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (20.45-b01 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
Problematic frame:
C  [cygwin1.dll+0xe38e7]

If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport/crash.jsp
The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
See problematic frame for where to report the bug.

I receive this error sometimes, but the confusing part Is i already have disabled UAC and I run eclipse Administrator.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Don't run Java as an administrator.  Just don't do it.  Seriously, don't.

Comment: Serious question:  why is cygwin involved in your VM?  Better question:  why are you running Java 6 in this day and age?

Comment: Sorry, I stole the error message because I forgot to copy it after restarting my JVM.

Comment: @Makoto Am not running Java as an administrator, I am running Eclipse as Administrator.

Comment: There's no difference.  Eclipse runs on top of Java, so that JVM has privileges it shouldn't.

Comment: @Makoto Ok so ill stop running Eclipse as an administrator?, Although it was occuring when i didn't run it as administrator, I tried this as a secondary precaution.

Comment: EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION isn't related to user privileges or UAC.  Running as administrator and turning off UAC aren't the solution.

Comment: Are you trying to run `java` in cygwin? Are you sure you have the latest version of Cygwin as this appears to be the cause.

Comment: Update your JDK. If the error persists, post the actual error message and not something you found on the net.